# This certificate is not valid because one of the certificate authorities in the certification path dose not appear to be allowed to issue certificates

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, certificate, signtool

[The issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbxTY.png) 
[another img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpSdr.png)

So I have made an SSC, and when I signed it to an exe file and checked the digital signatures tab, it said that the cert was unavailable. I have tried making a new SSC, and that didn't work. And yes, these certs are getting imported to the trusted roots authorities.

for it to not have an error.

Comment: [Main img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpSdr.png)